# Opening an excel file using Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

Protractor Query: our application generate a excel file which contains aome formulas. Now until I don't open the excel, it won't readable by exceljs. Is there any way I can open the excel and close it like we do robot in selenium?

Please Note that if i Open the file and keep at specified location below code works fine, but when i download the same from application and try to read it it wont work.

```
function compareExcelFromScreen(VerificationSection, file, row, column, SheetName, callback) {
var wrkbook = new Excel.Workbook();
var valFromExcel = null;
var filteredExcelValue = null;
var filteredScreenvalue = null;
var temp = null;
wrkbook.xlsx.readFile(file.toString()).then(function () {
    var worksheet = wrkbook.getWorksheet(SheetName);
    valFromExcel = worksheet.getRow(parseInt(row)).getCell(parseInt(column)).value;
}
```

}

Comment: are you using nodejs to run it?

Comment: why is it not readable by exceljs? maybe you need to try another module?

Comment: @Sargey As per development team, they have used some package to generate excel through XML, so until its not opened formulas within excel is not getting calculated. So i believe that is the reason exceljs is not able to read it.

Comment: Yes using nodejs to run

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of excel content and code where you are using exceljs @BhuvneshSainani

Comment: i Have updated the Code in Query itslef now.

Comment: Is this resolved now?